# Entity framework 5.0 context reload

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

When I edit data directly in the database, the modified fields are not updated in `ENTITY FRAMEWORK CONTEXT`, only new and deleted rows are updated. (using one `ObjectContext` for the whole workflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Context is like a cache memory apart from database. Nothing wrong with that, PLUS!, Context was made for that! So isn't recommended to use a single Context in your whole system (see Unity of Work).

Q: Okay, but I want to use just one Context in the whole workflow and this is a problem.

A: You will need to refresh the context whenever you need Context updated as database.

We have 2 options to solve that:

1 - To just refresh what you want, Context has `Refresh()` method.

Example code:

```
Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, WhatYouNeedToRefresh);
```

Documentation:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255.aspx
```

2 - You could set Context = null, and re-create again, it'll refresh the whole context, but I don't think that is good. I think refreshing just what you want is the best option.

Now just for joking, using Entity Framework is like a marriage, you'll marry with its good and bad things! :)

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone else - it looks like Context.Refresh no longer exists in EF 6.0.

What works for me instead is:

```
Context.Entry(WhatYouNeedToRefresh).Reload();
```